# Idiomatic way to convert a List to a Pair in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

There is an idiomatic approach to converting a `Pair` into a `List`:

```
Pair(a, b).toList()
```

No I am searching for the opposite process. My best approach looks like this:

```
Pair(list[0], list[1])
```

My problem with this is that I need to make a `List` value in code first for this to work. I would love something like this:

```
listOf(a, b).toPair()
```

Comment: How would you like to handle situations where the list size is != 2?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For a more general solution you could use the extension function [`zipWithNext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html)* which

> Returns a list of pairs of each two adjacent elements in this collection.

The example in the documentation explains it better:

```
val letters = ('a'..'f').toList()
val pairs = letters.zipWithNext()

println(letters) // [a, b, c, d, e, f]
println(pairs) // [(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), (d, e), (e, f)]
```

*note that this function is available since v1.2 of Kotlin.

Comment: Just append a `.single()` to the `zipWithNext()` call, and the solution would be perfect.

Answer (score 10):

You can make this extension for yourself:

```
fun <T> List<T>.toPair(): Pair<T, T> {
    if (this.size != 2) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("List is not of length 2!")
    }
    return Pair(this[0], this[1])
}
```

The error handling is up to you, you could also return a `Pair<T, T>?` with `null` being returned in the case where the `List` is not the correct length. You could also only check that it has at least 2 elements, and not require it to have exactly 2.

Usage is as you've described:

```
listOf(a, b).toPair()
```

Comment: This is not an idiomatic way though. @stan0 offered one.

Comment: Creating extensions that encapsulate some logic is pretty idiomatic.

Comment: @Ilya Yes of course, but it does not address the problem directly. It is idiomatic in another way.

Comment: I don't see how this doesn't solve your problem directly. It's not in the standard library because it's a very specific task, and could not be used generally, unlike `zipWithNext`. It does, however, provide both the precise syntax and result you were looking for, of which `zipWithNext` does neither, really.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an option that is chainable (for example I came across this when mapping a list of strings that I turned into a pair by splitting), I find this pattern useful:

```kotlin
yourList.let{ it[0] to it[1] } // this assumes yourList always has at least 2 values
```

Here it is in context:

```kotlin
val pairs: List<Pair<String,String>> = lines.map{ it.split(",").let{ it[0] to it[1] } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on @zsmb13's solution that avoids creating the exception explicitly and dereferencing the list by index:

```
fun <T> List<T>.toPair(): Pair<T, T> {
    require (this.size == 2) { "List is not of length 2!" }
    val (a, b) = this
    return Pair(a, b)
}
```